# Is there any good reason to default initialize a new QString?

Tags: c++, qt

I am confronted with some legacy Qt code and i see a lot things like this:

```
QString myString = QString();
```

From my point of view it is unnecessary.
Is there any good reason to do so?

Comment: My bet is that such code was written by former Java developer.

Comment: Doing just this `QString myString;` will produce the same string as in your example - a null string. So both forms are equivalent.

Comment: @vahancho: The concept of "null" `QString` is confusing, and only retained for backwards compatibility. In particular, `QString() == QString("")` but `QString()::isNull() == true` `while `QString("")::isNull() == false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no good reason. This is not specific to Qt, but a generic c++ behavior. Declaring a variable of any class type like this:

```
QString mystring
AnyObject myobject;
// etc.
```

will implicitly call [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) for the corresponding type.

Edit: as pointed in comment, this is only valid for class types (including structs and unions) but not for basic types (int, char, long, float, etc.).

Comment: Except of course that `int` is a non-class type, which does not have a constructor. And then `int int_value = int()` suddenly makes a huge difference.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I update the answer right now

Comment: "class and struct types" suggests that unions.are different from those. That's of course not formally the case. Unions, like structs, are also class types.

Comment: I know I can seem a bit picky at times, but since you link to cppreference it makes sense to be consistent. And they too use the formal definitions.

Comment: No I agree, you're right. But to be honest, I didn't know anything about union types 10 minutes ago. This is the first time I heard about it in 9 years. It's nice to see we never stop to learn. That's why I like asking and answering on SO. Have a nice day ;)

Comment: @Msalters Of course writing `type foo = type()` is silly in modern C++ - there's no reason to repeat the type. You'd write `int foo = {}` in general, I hope, or even just `auto foo = 0` for numeric types.

Comment: @KubaOber: True, but it is exactly that pattern which is subject of the question. And my point is that you can't just replace it as indicated in this question. Importantly, this also holds for templates. You can't just replace `T t = T();`  with `T t;`